# Adding the maximum value based on a condition in R

Tags: r

Following up on a previous question of mine in which the example given was ultimately different than what I needed. As always, thank you to the Stack community for your help. Y'all are amazing.

I have a data frame as follows:

```
data.frame(COLOR = c("BLUE", "BLUE: RED", "BLUE: GREEN", 
                     "BLUE: RED: GREEN", "RED", "RED: GREEN", 
                     "GREEN"),
           TOTAL = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3),
           N_CATS = c(0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0)) %>% 
  arrange(N_CATS)
```

For any row in which `N_CATS` is between the minimum and the maximum, in this case between 0 and 4, I need to add to the existing `TOTAL`, the `TOTAL` from the row with the maximum `N_CATS`. Thus, to any row in which `N_CATS` equals 1 or 3, I would add 1 to their total as this is the total from the row in which `N_CATS` equals 4. For any rows in which `N_CATS` is either the maximum or the minimum, we keep the previous `TOTAL`. My desired output is as follows:

```
COLOR           TOTAL   N_CATS     NEW_TOTAL
BLUE            1       0          1
GREEN           3       0          3
BLUE:RED        2       1          3
BLUE:GREEN      1       1          2
RED:GREEN       1       1          2 
RED             2       3          3    
BLUE:RED:GREEN  1       4          1
```

Does anyone know how to do this using a dplyr solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create a logical condition to add the 'TOTAL' with the value of 'TOTAL', where the 'N_CATS' is `max` (`which.max` - gives the index) for the rows where the 'N_CATS' elements are not `min` or `max`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(NEW_TOTAL = case_when(!N_CATS  %in% range(N_CATS) ~
                        TOTAL  +TOTAL[which.max(N_CATS)], 
       TRUE ~ TOTAL))
#             COLOR TOTAL N_CATS NEW_TOTAL
#1             BLUE     1      0         1
#2            GREEN     3      0         3
#3        BLUE: RED     2      1         3
#4      BLUE: GREEN     1      1         2
#5       RED: GREEN     1      1         2
#6              RED     2      3         3
#7 BLUE: RED: GREEN     1      4         1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COLOR = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L
), .Label = c("BLUE", "BLUE: GREEN", "BLUE: RED", "BLUE: RED: GREEN", 
"GREEN", "RED", "RED: GREEN"), class = "factor"), TOTAL = c(1, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1), N_CATS = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

how about that:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
mutate(NEW_TOTAL = if_else(N_CATS == 1 | N_CATS == 3,
                         TOTAL + 1,
                         TOTAL))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(NEW_TOTAL = 
           if_else(N_CATS %in% range(N_CATS),
                   TOTAL,
                   TOTAL[which.max(N_CATS)] + TOTAL)
         )
```

another one for you, lots of ways to approach this

Answer (score 0):

We can check if the `N_CATS` is in `range` which would generate a logical vector which is then multiplied to `TOTAL` of maximum value in `N_CATS` and added to original `TOTAL`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new_total = TOTAL +(!N_CATS %in% range(N_CATS)) * TOTAL[which.max(N_CATS)])

#             COLOR TOTAL N_CATS new_total
#1             BLUE     1      0         1
#2            GREEN     3      0         3
#3        BLUE: RED     2      1         3
#4      BLUE: GREEN     1      1         2
#5       RED: GREEN     1      1         2
#6              RED     2      3         3
#7 BLUE: RED: GREEN     1      4         1
```

This solution can also be changed easily to base R

```
transform(df, new_total = TOTAL + (!N_CATS %in% range(N_CATS)) * TOTAL[which.max(N_CATS)])
```